# MySQL match any value in list against any value in another list

Tags: mysql, filter, subquery

I have a load of code in place to 'filter' some records based on if a certain field appears in a list.

Currently `SELCT * FROM table1 ... AND value IN (8, 6, 4, 2, 9, 1, 3, 5, 7) ...`

With table1 structure :

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `table1` (
    `uniqueid` varchar(32) NOT NULL,
    `value` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
    ...
    PRIMARY KEY (`uniqueid`)
)
```

Now I have to store `value` in a separate table and there may well be more than one 'value' in the table.

New table1 structure:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `table1` (
    `uniqueid` varchar(32) NOT NULL,
    ...
    PRIMARY KEY (`uniqueid`)
)
```

New table2 structure

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `table2` (
    `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
    `uniqueid` varchar(32) NOT NULL,
    `value` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
    ...
    PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
)
```

You get the idea!

My question is how to check if any record in table2 for `uniqueid` is in the list given in the first example.

I considered using some sort of `COUNT` subquery but I'm not sure. I tried:

```
SELECT * FROM table1, table2 
            WHERE table1.uniqueid = table2.uniqueid 
            AND (SELECT COUNT(id) FROM table1, table2 
                       WHERE table2.uniqueid = table1.uniqueid ) > 0 
            AND table2.value IN (8, 6, ...
```

But it wasnt working and I don't really like the approach, feels very messy.

Any help appreciated.

Comment: could you provide the desired result set ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you wanted to find those values that exist in 2 tables, implement an `INNER JOIN`.

```
   SELECT UniqueID
   FROM Table1 t1
   INNER JOIN Table2 t2 
     ON t1.UniqueID = t2.UniqueID
   WHERE (YourCritiera);
```

Comment: I dont think this works. Table2 may contain several records for `uniqueid`, each with a different `value`. I need to know if any of the values in the 'IN' list match any of the values for `value` in table2

Comment: it seems theres been another suggestion of using this join, maybe I've understood incorrectly. Let me actually try it for a second.

Comment: My apologies, it did work. I didn't understand the logic of JOIN.